# Page search and console.log doesn't work in JSBin

Tags: javascript, jsbin

**What am I doing wrong, because "page search" (Ctrl-cmd / Ctrl-f) doesn't work in JSBin?**

http://jsbin.com/oqojan/42/edit

I try to search term "path2curve" in Javascript-window, but only the first match is found,  although the term exists on the Javascript-window few times.

I use Chrome version 22.0.1229.92 (Mac OS X 10.6.8). The same problem is with newest FF.

Ability to search within code is essential on developing. Now I have used a workaround to copy text to Ultraedit and find terms there and paste after modifications the code again in JSBin. I prefer JSBin over JSfiddle, because JSBin shows typed letters immediately and the text cursor moves as fast as it is moved. In JSFiddle if code is long (like Raphaël source), the hanging time can be seconds.

**The other problem in JSBin is that console.log(object) doesn't show object as traversable** (by clicking arrow symbol in Chrome Console), although in other pages objects are traversable.

Comment: JSBin is using an infinite scroll widget, so the whole JavaScript isn't actually in the DOM. Why aren't you searching in your code editor instead of JSBin? JSBin is not a replacement for a real IDE.

Comment: Because testing things in various browsers is easier and I see the results in various browsers immediately after typing and in JSBin code sharing and getting feedback is fast. Or is there some IDE that could do the same trick?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the searching problem I believe is fixed (or certainly when I test it in chrome, it yields the result).  jsbin (as do many others) uses codemirror, which is where the problem was.  It's since been upgraded, and I don't think it's a problem anymore.

Regarding the console.log - I'm not sure there's enough in your post to actually diagnose. I should add the custom console has been refactored recently and I know deep object exposure was updated.  Please do give it another test if you can.